# Require is failing when higher level path is not specified

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, require

I'm stumped on this issue and am hoping someone has seen it before. I'm using rvm and bundler, same as coworkers, but this is happening to me and not them. I can't figure out what weird configuration I have.

The issue has happened several times with different `require` statements fitting this pattern, but here are a couple of examples.

`require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'` on its own will give me `No such file to load`, but if I add a line above like this, it works:

```
require 'capybara-screenshot'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'
```

I've also seen this with `shoulda-matchers` - had to add this extra line on top of the other `require`:

```
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'shoulda/matchers/integrations/rspec'
```

Like I said, this affects me and not my coworkers working on the same app. I don't want to litter up our whole codebase with extra lines just for me, so I'd like to figure out why this is happening instead.

Comment: Is there any difference in how you start the tests, you and your coworkers? For example, in using or not using `bundle exec`?